# css element margin for Firefox with Linux OS

Tags: css, linux, firefox, margin

I designed this website, and I have been unable to place an the element ( div#endinglogo ) in a way that renders properly for firefox / Linux operating system users.

http://motivacionenlinea.com/

I am working with all browsers in windows 7, and although the design appears as it should in the firefox with MY operating system, my guesses to fix firefox/Linux have not worked.

My questions is what is proper margin to give to element div#endinglogo for it to appear where it should.

I have attached two images below.

The first shows how I want the header to look:
http://postimage.org/image/rsd27dvo/

The second shows how I been told it appears in browser firefox when using linux operating system:
http://postimage.org/image/rtgr3pqc/

I have a php file that serves firefoxLinux.css file, or at least that is the intent. Is this file being loaded when you see this website through firefox/linux?

Thank you for your help

Comment: Since you're on FF, install Firebug, look at the CSS setup in there (the computed values, in particular), and figure out which elements have different computed values - that'll be your layout difference.

Comment: I am working in windows 7, and even though I USE FIREBUG I am unable to properly measure the correct margin in a FireFox Linuz operating system display. What I am looking for, is a Linux operating system user to go to firefox and figure this measure for me. Since I cannot do this b/c I have a different operating system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `firefox.css`, you have a different negative top margin for your `div#endinglogo`. Make it `-110px` (like it is in your `chrome.css` file) and it should work.

On a related sidenote though, why are you creating multiple stylesheets for different browsers? For most things there are solutions that work consistently across browsers and operating systems, and only in a few cases do you need special styles (i.e. for IE, maybe some older versions of firefox). I think if you were to consolidate your styles you would run into less problems. Of course that's just my two cents.

Comment: The thing is that if I add -110 for firefox.css , the page looks wrong in Windows. This is why I created firefoxLinux.css but given that you retrieved firefox.css instead of firefoxLinux.css I imagine the firefox/Linux css file is not loading.

Comment: I have changed the code, could you check if the firefoxLinux.css was loaded? I have set the margin to -110px in firefoxLinux.css file   Thank you

Comment: I'm not seeing the problem in Linux/Firefox 3.6. It is loading firefoxLinux.css. But I'm *really* surprised that you're needing to make those kind of hacks to support the same browser on different OS.

Comment: @Spudley RE: I'm a beginner designer and I felt that serving a dedicated style sheet per browser engine was the most organized way to address the different behaviors. Could you confirm that the header of the page looks like image one listed on the post? http://postimage.org/image/rsd27dvo/ Thank you